# Juego de punto y fama en Java

Tags: java

soy estudiante de 1 semestre de ing. de sistemas, tengo que realizar un juego de "punto y fama" en java y estoy bastante enredado a decir verdad.
El juego trata de generar 4 numeros aleatorios que no se repitan, el usuario tratara de adivinar cual es el numero.
Si acierta en un numero, pero no esta en la poscicion correcta es un punto, y si acierta el numero en la poscicion correcta es una fama, es esto básicamente.

Ahora el problema es que no se como almacenar los numeros que me genera el codigo para poder compararlos con los que ingresa el usuario, tengo esto:

```
package prueba;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 *
 * @author Alvaro
 */
public class Prueba {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int n=4;  //numeros aleatorios
       int k=n;  //auxiliar;
        int[] numeros=new int[n];
        int[] resultado=new int[n];
        Random rnd=new Random();
        int res;


        //se rellena una matriz ordenada del 1 al 9(1..n)
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            numeros[i]=i+1;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            res=rnd.nextInt(k);            
            resultado[i]=numeros[res];
            numeros[res]=numeros[k-1];
            k--;

        }
         //se imprime el resultado;
        System.out.println("El resultado de la matriz es:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           int na1=resultado[i],na2=resultado[i],na3=resultado[i],na4=resultado[i];


        System.out.println(resultado[i]);


            System.out.println(na1+"xxx"+na2+"xxx"+na3+"xxx"+na4);
        }

   }
}
```

Les agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Con qué te refieres a almacenados? Segun yo veo los valores que se generan estan en la variable `int[] numeros`

Answer (score 1):

esos datos ya quedan guardados en el momento que tu haces este for:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            res=rnd.nextInt(k);            
            resultado[i]=numeros[res];
            numeros[res]=numeros[k-1];
            k--;

        }
```

pero según te entendí el código que necesitas es este

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author Camilo Rodriguez
 */
public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=4;  //numeros aleatorios
       int k=n;  //auxiliar;
        int[] numeros=new int[n];
        int[] resultado=new int[n];
        Random rnd=new Random();
        int res;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //se rellena una matriz ordenada del 1 al 9(1..n)
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            numeros[i]=i+1;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            res=rnd.nextInt(k);            
            resultado[i]=numeros[res];
            numeros[res]=numeros[k-1];
            k--;

        }
//       ESTAS LINES COMENTADAS SON PARA MOSTRAR LA MATRIZ AL PRINCIPIO PARA COMPROBAR SI EL PROGRAMA SIRVE
//        for (int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
//            System.out.println( resultado[i]);
//            
//        }
        System.out.println("ingrese el numero");
        int numero = 0;
        numero = scanner.nextInt();
        int posicion = 0;
        System.out.println("ingrese la posicion");
        posicion = scanner.nextInt();
        if (numero == resultado[posicion-1]) {
            System.out.println("fama!");
            System.out.println("ingrese el numero");
            numero = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("ingrese la posicion");
            posicion = scanner.nextInt();
            if (numero == resultado[posicion-1]) {
                System.out.println("fama!");
                System.out.println("ingrese el numero");
                numero = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("ingrese la posicion");
                posicion = scanner.nextInt();
                if (numero == resultado[posicion-1]) {
                    System.out.println("fama!");
                    System.out.println("ingrese el numero");
                    numero = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("ingrese la posicion");
                    posicion = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (numero == resultado[posicion-1]) {
                        System.out.println("FELICIDADES HAS GANADO");
                        posicion = scanner.nextInt();
            }else{
            System.out.println("punto");
         //se imprime el resultado;
        System.out.println("El resultado de la matriz es:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){          
        System.out.println(resultado[i]+"\n");

        }
        }
            }else{
            System.out.println("perdio");
         //se imprime el resultado;
        System.out.println("El resultado de la matriz es:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println(resultado[i]+"\n");
        }
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("perdio");
         //se imprime el resultado;
        System.out.println("El resultado de la matriz es:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println(resultado[i]+"\n");
        }
        }

    }else{
            System.out.println("punto");
         //se imprime el resultado;
        System.out.println("El resultado de la matriz es:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println(resultado[i]+"\n");
    }
    }

    }
}
```